# Migrating Thunderbird Profile from Windows 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, thunderbird

I'm very new to this. I've trawled the forums to try to find out how to set up Thunderbird in Ubuntu and transfer my existing profile from Windows but I can't work it out. Please help.

Step-by-step instructions like you're talking to the impaired (because you are)  would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to answer this is to point you to the knowledge base article from Mozilla on moving your profile from one computer to another.

[Moving your Thunderbird profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder)

It gives you the steps to follow as well as a link for [moving from windows to linux](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_from_Windows_to_Linux) that you should read through as well.

Before attempting any move I would back up your Thunderbird profile from Windows as well.

Comment: Also look at: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird

Comment: Hey, thanks Mark. I stuffed around for a bit and came up with a bit of a "work-around" sort of resolution to what I needed. It's a bit embarrassing to say but I was really just chasing the addresses so, what I did was, while I was in windows I selected all the addresses in the address book and copied them into the text area of an email. I sent that email to my web based email address. I then switched over to Ubuntu and received that email in Thunderbird and Thunderbird collected the addresses. Haha. It worked...